# Show selected item in list view

Tags: android, listview

I want to highlight the selected item in list view. There is one scenario in which if user selects any item from list view, list view  freezes and if user again comes to that screen that item will show as selected. (Note that this is not the case every time). So Is there some way by which I can show some item selected say via some background color. But this need to be done in activity class file **NOT IN ADAPTER**.

I tried

```
        MYListAdapter adapter = (GenericListAdapter) lvList.getAdapter();
        View view = adapter.getView(position, null, null);
        view.setBackgroundColor(color.holo_orange_dark);
```

But its not working as expected. Can any body suggest me any thing.

Comment: Do the highlighting in your adapter

Comment: could you please post some codes so we can help you more? I thought of overriding getView(...) this is the best way to do it.

Comment: @ArunCThomas any way to do it from activity clas?? I am using a my list adapter which is generic and used across app. so is there any other way to do it??

Comment: @WilliamFox That would be my last option, as I dont want to make any change in adapter. In adapter it a minute work. but i want it from activity class.

Answer (score 0):

`adapter.getView(position, null, null)` creates a new view, and not return view which is used in listView. You can try to get listView and get its child by position. Smth like that:

> lvList.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(color.holo_orange_dark);

But I think it's not the right way, because ListView can recreate view at any time.
So the right way is adapter..

Comment: lvList.getChildAt(position). This line is returning null

Answer (score 0):

you can see apiDemo->Views->Lists->Activate items.It's very simple,just setChoiceMode and provide a backgroud selector.
By the way,you should see android4.x apiDemo.